# Calculating the limit of a sequence that includes Binomial Coefficients.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, binomial-coefficients

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{n \choose k}2^{-n}$$, for a set $k \in \mathbb{N}$

I'm trying to evaluate this limit but I really don't know how to proceed when expanding the expression. I've seen people use Stirling's approximation to solve similar problems but that is not something that we have been taught so I don't think it's expected from us to solve it that way.

Comment: Consider rewriting $\binom{n}{k}$ as $\dfrac{n\frac{k}{~}}{k!}$ where $n\frac{k}{~}$ is notation for the falling factorial $\underbrace{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)}_{k~\text{terms}}$.  This is merely a polynomial of degree $k$ as compared to $2^{-n}$ which is exponential.  What would you have done if you were asked about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+n}{2^n}$?  What would you have done if you were asked about $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n^3+2n-7}{2^n}$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hopital's?

Comment: @JMoravitz I would use L΄Hopital's rule to solve those. I can kinda see that the limit of the original problem is probably 0, however I'm not really familiar with the notation you used.

Comment: @DS I don't see why not, it hasn't come up yet but it's been covered before.

Comment: @user1171376 I defined the notation in the comment itself... I didn't expect you to have seen that choice of notation before.  The punchline I was trying to get across is that $\binom{n}{k}\cdot 2^{-n} = \dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot 2^{-n} = \dfrac{1}{k!}\cdot \dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}\cdot 2^{-n}$ and to recognize that $\dfrac{1}{k!}$ is just a constant number, and that $\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ is just a polynomial of $n$ of degree $k$.

Comment: Rewriting your expression $$\binom{n}{k}2^{-n} = \frac{(n-k+1)(n-k+2)\cdots(n-1)n}{k!2^n}\le \frac{n^k}{k!2^n}$$When you take the limit to infinity, you get an indeterminate form $\infty/\infty$. Apply L'Hopital's rule $k$ times on the last expression. What do you get? Note that the original limit should be $\ge 0$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I see it now, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

A fancy yet elementary way: take a look at the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom nk 2^{-n}$$

Let us use D'Alembert's Test to check convergence (as this is a positive series):

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\binom{n+1}k 2^{-n-1}}{\binom nk2^{-n}}=\frac{2^n(n+1)!\, k!\,(n-k)!}{2^{n+1}k!\,(n+1-k)\,n! }=\frac12\cdot\frac{n+1}{n+1-k}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac12<1$$

We then get the above series converges and thus the series' general term sequence converges to zero.